# Stack implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stack

I'm new to Swift and iOS programming.

I'm trying to test out a simple algorithm and need an array of Stacks. Don't have to be anything fancy (Stacks of Ints will do).

I got the Stack implementation from [The Swift Programming Language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_283):

```
struct IntStack {
    var items = [Int]()
    mutating func push(item: Int) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Int {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
    mutating func count() -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    mutating func show() {
        println(items)
    }
}
```

The count and show functions are my contribution. But when I try to declare an array of Stacks I get an error...

```
var lines = IntStack()[5]
```

"IntStack" does not have a member named subscript

I'm guessing it has something to do with Optionals but can figure out what it is.

Any help?

Comment: `[5]` is apparently what Swift refers to as a subscript.  I'm not a Swift expert, but usually "subscripts" require either an array or a custom object that you've added an array-like indexer to.

Comment: Try : var lines = IntStack(items: [5]).  I suppose you wanted to create a stack of int with an array containing 5.

Answer (score 16):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.3.1

### Generic Stack Implementation

> Stackable protocol

```
protocol Stackable {
    associatedtype Element
    func peek() -> Element?
    mutating func push(_ element: Element)
    @discardableResult mutating func pop() -> Element?
}

extension Stackable {
    var isEmpty: Bool { peek() == nil }
}
```

> Stack

```
struct Stack<Element>: Stackable where Element: Equatable {
    private var storage = [Element]()
    func peek() -> Element? { storage.last }
    mutating func push(_ element: Element) { storage.append(element)  }
    mutating func pop() -> Element? { storage.popLast() }
}

extension Stack: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Stack<Element>, rhs: Stack<Element>) -> Bool { lhs.storage == rhs.storage }
}

extension Stack: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "\(storage)" }
}
    
extension Stack: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Self.Element...) { storage = elements }
}
```

### Usage

```
var stack = Stack<Int>()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)
print(stack.peek())
print(stack.pop())
print(stack)
print(stack == Stack<Int>())
stack = [3,2,1]
print(stack)
```

Answer (score 7):

There's no problem with what you're doing there - that's just not the syntax for declaring an array. If you want an array of 5 stacks, you can do this:

```
[IntStack(), IntStack(), IntStack(), IntStack(), IntStack()]
```

Or, you can initialise the array like this:

```
Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: IntStack())
```

Also, you don't need to mark your functions as `mutating` unless they actually mutate the structure - so `count()` and `show()` don't need it.

Comment: I don't think that you need `Repeat` here, `Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: IntStack())` should work as well.

Comment: Thanks guys! I used: Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: IntStack()) and removed the mutating from count() and show() (never use CMD+C CMD+V while programming), and it worked! This Array instantiation syntax is very weird to me, but I guess I got the point. Thanks again!!

Comment: @PlinioVilela this is ancient but seems like this should be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to just extend arrays with stack specific methods. This might or might not be what you want, depending on if you want to disallow array like access.

```swift
protocol Stack {
    associatedtype Element
    
    mutating func push(item: Element)
    
    // allows discarding the result without generating a warning.
    @discardableResult
    mutating func pop() -> Element?
    
    func peek() -> Element?
    
    var count: Int { get }
}

extension Array: Stack {
    mutating func push(item: Element) {
        self.append(item)
    }
    
    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        if let last = self.last {
            self.remove(at: self.count - 1)
            return last
        }
        
        return .none
    }
    
    func peek() -> Element? {
        self.last
    }
}
```

Simple test case:

```swift
class StackTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func testExample() throws {
        var stack = Array<Int>()
        
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.peek(), .none, "stack is empty, peek returns none")
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.pop(), .none, "stack is empty, pop returns none")

        stack.push(item: 0)
        stack.push(item: 1)
        stack.push(item: 2)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.peek(), 2)
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.pop(), 2)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.peek(), 1)
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.pop(), 1)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.peek(), 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(stack.pop(), 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to declare the size of the stack when you init it. Jus calling this should be enough.

```
var lines = IntStack()
```

Also note that your count() and show() methods should not be mutating since they don't modify the struct in any way.

Comment: OP is trying to declare an array of stacks, not a single stack with a particular size.

Answer (score 1):

Just look into this code. Stack example with generic data type and without using the array.

```
class Node<T>: CustomStringConvertible {

let value: T
var next: Node?

var description: String {
    guard let next = next else { return "\(value)" }
    return "\(value)\n" + String(describing: next)
}

init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
}
}


// Stack  class to hold all items
class Stack<T>: CustomStringConvertible {

var top: Node<T>?

var description: String {
    guard let top = top else { return "---- Stack is EMPTY ----" }
    return "---- Stack Begin ----\n" + String(describing: top) + "\n---- Stack End ----"
}

// push
func push(_ value: T) {
    let currentTop = top
    top = Node(value: value)
    top?.next = currentTop
}

@discardableResult
func pop() -> T? {
    let currentTop = top
    top = top?.next
    return currentTop?.value
}

@discardableResult
func peek() -> T? {
    return top?.value
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent implementation! One thought: I think it  should be:

```
func peek() -> Element? { storage.last }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a Stack implementation using Swift Generics,

```
struct Fruit {
let fruitName : String
let color : String
init(_ name: String,_ color: String) {
    self.fruitName = name
    self.color = color
}
}

let fruit1 = Fruit("Apple", "Red")
let fruit2 = Fruit("Grapes", "Green")

let fruitStack = Stack<Fruit>()
fruitStack.push(fruit1)
fruitStack.push(fruit2)

let fruitFfromStack = fruitStack.pop()
print("Fruit popped from Stack, Name : \(String(describing: fruitFfromStack?.fruitName)) ,Color : \(String(describing: fruitFfromStack?.color))")
let fruitFfromStack1 = fruitStack.pop()
print("Fruit popped from Stack, Name : \(String(describing: fruitFfromStack1?.fruitName)) ,Color : \(String(describing: fruitFfromStack1?.color))")
```

Full code is here :

https://reactcodes.blogspot.com/2019/01/generic-stack-implementation-with.html

Comment: And you are not showing any Stack implementation at all.